# Grab all text (including new lines) with Regex

Tags: regex, python-re

I'm trying to figure out how to grab all the text after `[text](URL)`, but I'm having difficulty including the entire text after it because of the new lines (`\n\n`). I'm currently trying variations of `(?<=.\)\n\n)(.*\n+)`, but it's only including the next paragraph.

Here's what the text looks like:

```
---
layout: post
title: "13 - First Principles of AGI Safety with Richard Ngo"
date: 2022-03-30 22:15 -0700
categories: episode
---

[Google Podcasts link](https://podcasts.google.com/feed/aHR0cHM6Ly9heHJwb2RjYXN0LmxpYnN5bi5jb20vcnNz/episode/OTlmYzM1ZjEtMDFkMi00ZTExLWExYjEtNTYwOTg2ZWNhOWNi)

How should we think about artificial general intelligence (AGI), and the risks it might pose? What constraints exist on technical solutions to the problem of aligning superhuman AI systems with human intentions? In this episode, I talk to Richard Ngo about his report analyzing AGI safety from first principles, and recent conversations he had with Eliezer Yudkowsky about the difficulty of AI alignment.

Topics we discuss:
- [The nature of intelligence and AGI](#agi-intelligence-nature)
  - [The nature of intelligence](#nature-of-intelligence)
  - [AGI: what and how](#agi-what-how)
  - [Single vs collective AI minds](#single-collective-ai-minds)
- [AGI in practice](#agi-in-practice)
  - [Impact](#agi-impact)
  - [Timing](#agi-timing)
  - [Creation](#agi-creation)
  - [Risks and benefits](#agi-risks-benefits)
- [Making AGI safe](#making-agi-safe)
  - [Robustness of the agency abstraction](#agency-abstraction-robustness)
  - [Pivotal acts](#pivotal-acts)
- [AGI safety concepts](#agi-safety-concepts)
  - [Alignment](#ai-alignment)
  - [Transparency](#transparency)
  - [Cooperation](#cooperation)
- [Optima and selection pressures](#optima-selection-pressures)
- [The AI alignment research community](#ai-alignment-research-community)
  - [Updates from Yudkowsky conversation](#yudkonversation-updates)
  - [Corrections to the community](#community-corrections)
  - [Why others don't join](#why-others-dont-join)
- [Richard Ngo as a researcher](#ngo-as-researcher)
- [The world approaching AGI](#world-approaching-agi)
- [Following Richard's work](#following-richards-work)

**Daniel Filan:**
Hello, everybody. Today, I'll be speaking with Richard Ngo. Richard is a researcher at OpenAI, where he works on AI governance and forecasting. He also was a research engineer at DeepMind, and designed the course ["AGI Safety Fundamentals"](https://www.eacambridge.org/agi-safety-fundamentals). We'll be discussing his report, [AGI Safety from First Principles](https://www.alignmentforum.org/s/mzgtmmTKKn5MuCzFJ), as well as his [debate with Eliezer Yudkowsky](https://www.alignmentforum.org/s/n945eovrA3oDueqtq) about the difficulty of AI alignment. For links to what we're discussing, you can check the description of this episode, and you can read the transcripts at [axrp.net](https://axrp.net/). Well, Richard, welcome to the show.

**Richard Ngo:**
Thanks so much for having me.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can afford to read in this entire text into a string variable, you may use `re.search` here:

```py
s = re.search(r'\[.*?\]\(https?://.*?\)\s+(.*)', text, flags=re.S)
print(s.group(1)))
```

This prints the text you seem to want:

> How should we think about artificial general intelligence (AGI), and the risks it might pose? What constraints exist on technical solutions to the problem of aligning superhuman AI systems with human intentions? In this episode, I talk to Richard Ngo about his report analyzing AGI safety from first principles, and recent conversations he had with Eliezer Yudkowsky about the difficulty of AI alignment...

Note that we are doing this regex find in dot all mode, so that `.*` will match across newlines.

Comment: Oh cool, another way to do it. Just figured out a hackier way to do it, but yeah thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to opt for the following approach:

```
end = re.search('\[(Google Podcasts link)\]\((.+)\)\n\n)', text).end()
text = text[end:]
```

So I just look for the text I want to start the text afterwards, and just use the `.end()` to slice the text string where I want to.

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be 1 occurrence, you could also use split with the pattern:

```
(?m)^\s*\[[^][]*]\(https?://[^\s()]*\)\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?m)` Enable multiline
- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match option whitespace character
- `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]`
- `\(https?://[^\s()]*\)` Match an url between parenthesis
- `\s*` Match trailing whitespace characters

See the matches at the  [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/37w47r/1)

Example

```
result = re.split(r"(?m)^\s*\[[^][]*]\(https?://[^\s()]*\)\s*", text)
print(result[1])
```

Or more specific

```
result = re.split(r"(?m)^\s*\[Google Podcasts link]\(https?://[^\s()]*\)\s*", text)
print(result[1])
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2WkSqX).